# Rules in htaccess files blocking connection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have htaccess file (created by other person) which is blocking subdomains with its rules.

Please find here the code:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

What it does:

If I type `www.test.com/about-us`, it opens `about-us.php`.

What I want to achieve:

I want to open `new_test` folder, which is a path for my subdomain. However, current rules treat it as a file rule & not folder rule. Can anybody help in this? I have very little knowledge about htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a specific rule(s) for your **new_test** folder, before your generic rule eg.

```
....
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/new_test  [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /new_test/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: It still throws an error 'Sorry currently service is not available'.

Comment: temporarily change the [NC,L] to [R,NC,L] for the **new_test**  rule, and confirm the error is coming from /new_test/index.php, which i presume physically exists on your server (please confirm)

Comment: Yes, the file does physically exist on the server. And yes, it still throws an error even after making a change you mention.

Comment: Try sticking an image and a dummy **php** file in the **/new_test/** directory, eg. create a **test.php**, that just contains:  <?php phpinfo(); ?>   If you can retrieve both of these the issue lies in your new **index.php** and not the rewrite.

Comment: That was indeed true, my mistake. It went fine. Thanks a ton :)